# Sorting Devexpress ComboBoxEdit date items

Tags: c#, date, sorting, combobox, devexpress

I have an issue while sorting out dates in a `ComboBoxEdit`.
Using this line of code :

```
cbeDates.Sorted = true
```

Sorts the items in a weird way. The output is :

```
01/01/2013
01/02/2013
01/03/2013
.... 
02/01/2013
02/02/2013
....
```

But I want the following expected output :

```
01/01/2013
02/01/2013
.... 
01/02/2013
02/02/2013
```

Did you guys ever deal with this kind of issue ?
Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: how do you set the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sort works alphabetically. You can sort the datasource and then bind it to combobox or add the items in a sorted order.

Another solution is to use the IComparable interface. The ComboBoxEdit performs the comparison of objects using the System.Collections.Comparer class. For sample code, please take a look at the links below.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B97090 
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A304

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AseemGautam. The easiest way is clearly to set the property `Sorted` to `false` and to bind the `ComboBoxEdit` with a sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

In Properties, try setting the Display Format and Edit Format to DateTime d